# Кешированный ajax запрос возврашает 200 вместо 304

Tags: symfony3

Проблема в следующем: я отправляю ajax запрос JSON справочника
однако всегда приходит ответ со статусом 200.

код запроса:

```
 public function getDataAjaxAction(Request $request){
    $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Land')->find(0);
    $response = new JsonResponse($data->getJSON());
    $response->setEtag(md5($response->getContent()));
    $response->setPublic();
    $response->isNotModified($request);
    return $response;
}
```

app.php:

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

сервер nginx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка или как её найти.

Comment: А в чём проблема, собственно? Почему должен быть не 200-й статус?

Comment: Не туда смотрел. Все кешируется. Если посмотреть через firefox то там есть графа передано. В ней как раз и находится фраза "кэшировано" Спасибо огромное

Answer (score -1):

Не туда смотрел. Все кешируется. Если посмотреть через firefox то там есть графа передано. В ней как раз и находится фраза "кэшировано" Спасибо огромное – Nikolay Korotkov 1 минуту назад

Comment: такие вопросы надо закрывать, чтобы не засорять интернет ;-)